# NSCollectionView Auto-Resize Subview with Auto-Layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, nscollectionview

I am trying to achieve a stacked arrangement of simple NSViews, and for that I'm using an NSCollectionView bound to a Dictionary Controller. The result I have so far is below:

[image: Normal]

The labels on the left are bound to the controller item keys and the SegmentedControl selectedIndex to the item values.

Problem is, I have no idea how to force the subviews within NSCollectionView to conform to the container width; what happens is, they maintain their own width and when the NSCollectionView becomes too narrow horizontal scrollbar appears, like below:

[image]

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107755/can-nscollectionview-autoresize-the-width-of-its-subviews-to-display-one-column) (and the "inverse", [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431097/resizing-nscollectionview-to-fit-inner-items?rq=1)), and I've never worked much with Autolayout beyond trivial things to be honest. I am wondering, with all the fanciness that AutoLayout brings with it, is there a way of dealing with this issue without resorting to coding and using events/notifications? (I understand that observing NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification is an alternative, right?)

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I wonder if there is a way to do it from IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple in fact: Switch to a view-based `NSTableView`. `NSCollectionView` is not intended for the use described in the question. With `NSTableView`, you get the resizing behaviour by default and for free.

It also works whether you're using Bindings or Datasource, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I mean  iOS `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`. Is there any alternative for macOS?

Comment: Umm what you're asking is a totally different beast.. I'd suggest specifically asking for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just did something very similar - except using an `NSSplitView` subclass - so if I understand your question correctly you'd want to setup constraints for the subviews to attach to the sides of your superview like this:

```
NSDictionary * viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(filler);
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[filler]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:viewsDict]];
```

You might also have to fiddle with the **Content Compression Resistance Priority** parameter of you subviews to achieve the desired results.

Also note that when targeting OS X 10.9 exclusively there's the new [`NSStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-TRANSLATED_CHAPTER_965-10_9StackView) class:

"*NSStackView is a new class in OS X 10.9. It is used to layout horizontal or vertical stacks of views using auto layout. Necessary constraints will automatically be created and modified when adding and removing views from a stack view to maintain a cohesive layout.*"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I totally forgot to mention that I'm using bindings (edited question), and that's one of the reasons I want to keep using NSCollectionView (it's really easy to use). I played a bit with the Content Compression Resistance Priority, setting it to a lower value ( < 500, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority) ), but nothing changed... it seems for CollectionView's children different rules apply?

Comment: Is there a way to set this up from IB?