# Cocoa - How to change the size of NSCollectionViewItem and layout programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I want to change the layout of the NSCollectionView programmatically with 3 buttons, each button will change the layout of the collection view - 2, 3, 4 columns per row. And the NSCollectionViewItem size has to be auto-resized.

I tried searching all day, but found nothing helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074260/1091402) and see if you can tweak it to support multiple columns?

Comment: I actually coincidentally have been trying to do something very similar.  Currently what I'm doing to get it to work is in the awakefromnib of the superview(`NSCollectionView` in your case), I check the sizes of the subviews(`NSButton` in your case), and add those sizes together and resize the superview with the new frame.  I am aware this is a horrible lazy solution but I'm hoping to get my alternative solution of using auto-layout to work.  I have tried programmatically setting constraints on the superview to resize it depending on the subviews, but it didn't work :\  I am following this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't satisfy with Apple's stock NSCollectionView. Fortunately, Jonathan made a nice custom collection view called [JNWCollectionView](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView) for cocoa which has very similar mechanics with UICollectionView on iOS.